# 3d mouse aim camera 3rd person vertical C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, camera

I'm trying to make mouse aim camera that rotate my Player horizontally and vertically, look at Player and keep constant distance.
In that version it works fine but I can't make it horizontal also.
Each version camera freezes and I rotate my player itself or so.
I'm new to programming so I it's propably easy task with proper target.transform.eulerAngles.y assigning also to vertical but I cannot do it.

```
public class MouseAimCamera : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject target;
    public float rotateSpeed = 5;
    Vector3 offset;

    void Start() {
        offset = target.transform.position - transform.position;
    }

    void LateUpdate() {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotateSpeed;
        target.transform.Rotate(0, horizontal, 0);

        float desiredAngle = target.transform.eulerAngles.y;
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, desiredAngle, 0);
        transform.position = target.transform.position - (rotation * offset);

        transform.LookAt(target.transform);
    }
}
```

I'd be glad if any of you can help me.

Comment: Can you update your question to give more detail on what you're looking for?  Try to be specific about what what you want the mouse to control, and what orientation you want to camera to have.  If you want the camera always oriented upward, then you have to clamp the vertical rotation to prevent a snapping gimbal rotation when you rotate past straight up or down.

Answer (score 2):

This will rotate in world space, which will probably feel wrong at some angles since the camera is not always oriented straight up.

```
public class MouseAimCamera : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject target;
    public float rotateSpeed = 5;

    void Start() {
        transform.parent = target.transform;
        transform.LookAt(target.transform);
    }

    void LateUpdate() {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotateSpeed;
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotateSpeed;
        target.transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, Vector3.up, horizontal);
        target.transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, Vector3.left, vertical);
    }
}
```

This will rotate in local space, and might feel more natural depending on what you're trying to build.  This is close to your original solution, so i'm guessing it's not what you want.

```
public class MouseAimCamera : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject target;
    public float rotateSpeed = 5;

    void Start() {
        transform.parent = target.transform;
        transform.LookAt(target.transform);
    }

    void LateUpdate() {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotateSpeed;
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotateSpeed;
        target.transform.Rotate(vertical, horizontal, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx it's good direction of what I had in mind.
However there is still problem in it.
It moves up down and left right correctly but when you move your mouse to one of the corners camera starts to rotate on z axis.
I'd like to freeze that. 
Enable rotation on that axis with "Q" and "W" buttons.
Another problem is that camera stick to the right profile of the player.
It should stay behind him.

Comment: transform.parent = target.transform locks the camera into the position that its start in.  If you want it behind the player, then place it behind the player in the scene.

Comment: Thx a lot! script fits my expectations. I just had to set -vertical because your script works like invert mouse in vertical directions :)
And  moving camera in right position in a scene solved facing problem.